# Is it possible to solve CUDA memory fragmentation issue?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, cuda, memory-fragmentation

I'm trying to allocate some memory but sometimes get error "out of memory". **cudaMemGetInfo** says that available more memory that I need. So, problem in memory fragmentation. Is it possible to fix this problem? Is it possible to place elements in memory not one by one and fragment to few peaces that I can place in memory?

Answer (score 3):

If you get "out of memory" because of memory fragmentation, then there is some error in the way that you work with memory!! You are responsible for fragmenting that memory, consider a redesign of your program and for example use a pool of memory to avoid too much new/delete to avoid fragmenting memory

Comment: Is exist library that implements memory pool to CUDA?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, take a look at `libhoard`. I don't remember the site but googling `libhoard` will help you.

Comment: I found this library but I found nothing about using it for CUDA device memory allocation.